# iPad Modal "Log In" View

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've never developed for the iPad before (just iPhone) and there are some views you see on an iPad that you cannot do on an iPhone. Specifically, I'm trying to create a modal 'login/register' type view and I'd like it to mimic the look and feel of the Log In view in the Zillow iPad app.

In Zillow when you press 'Log In' (or Settings for that matter), the background darkens and a window appears in the middle of the screen modally with a flip animation about it's horizontal axis. Here you are given a view containing buttons, text fields, toggle switches, etc.

Is there a cocoa class for this type of view on the iPad? Can you have a regular UIViewController not take up the entire screen and display 'on top' of the root view controller?

EDIT: Just discovered in the View Controller Attributes Inspector, under Simulated Metrics for Size, there is the Form Sheet option which looks similar to what I am going for. These will display on-top of root views?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You present the view modally, or in a storyboard, do a modal segue. In the inspector for the segue, you can change the presentation from default to "form sheet".

If you're doing the modal presentation in code, you can set the modalPresentationStyle property of the controller you're presenting to UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

As you said in your edit, in the storyboard, you can change the size of the view you want to present by setting the size in Simulated Metrics to "form sheet". However, this has no effect on what size the view will appear at run time. It's only used so you can properly layout your view visually. You need to use one of the ways I mentioned above to get the view to appear at the form sheet size.